# xcode sqlite3 how to copy database from bundle to documents folder?

Tags: xcode, sqlite

How to copy the database from the bundle to the Documents folder (from xcode interface or programmaticly)? I want to use sqlite3 database to insert/update. I have made database and put into application structure using xcode interfce (drag/drop).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone (iOS): copying files from main bundle to documents folder error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246109/iphone-ios-copying-files-from-main-bundle-to-documents-folder-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSFileManager's [`-copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:) method to copy the file. If you prefer to work with URLs, there's also [`-copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtURL:toURL:error:).

There's a fine example of how to do this in the question [iPhone (iOS): copying files from main bundle to documents folder error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3246109/643383).

Comment: first: check file exist, next: copy file on viewdidload?

Comment: @ksprs8 I'd do it in the app delegate, perhaps as part of your app delegate's `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. Sure, check whether the file already exists at the destination if you like, and do the copy if not. That's not strictly necessary: `copyItemAtPath:...` will (according to the docs) abort and return an error if the file already exists at the destination. But it does seem like a good idea to avoid even attempting to overwrite a data file.

Comment: Can you put in (show) complete -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions code what you are using?

Comment: @ksprs8 See updated answer. You should be able to use the code provided in the question I linked. That Q looks at copying an entire directory, but if you change the paths to include your file name, it should work fine.