# How to change app resourses?

Tags: ios, resources

I have some json-resourses (txt-files) in my app. I need not only to read them but also to change them programatically. How should i do it?

Comment: Why can't you write to the JSON file?

Comment: See @danielbeard answer below. All this files are stored in the main bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the files to the Documents folder, then you can read and write to them. Anything stored in the main bundle is read only.

See this answer for more: [iPhone (iOS): copying files from main bundle to documents folder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246109/iphone-ios-copying-files-from-main-bundle-to-documents-folder-error)